# sed or awk replace after ignoring N matches

Tags: bash, awk, replace, sed

I have a repetitive text, I want to carefully replace one label with another several times, I don mind repeating *sed* *awk* or another method. Therefore I would want to first replace the first two matches, then after the first 4, 6, etc. I don't want a *for*, I just need something like the code below, I want to skip the first two matches and then increase that number.

```
sed 's/foo/bar/2g' fileX 
awk '{ sub(/foo/,"bar"); print }' fileX
```

here is an example. Two occurrences per line

```
blastx -q specie.fa -db pep -num 6 -max 1 -o 6 > specie.x.outfmt6
blastp -q specie.pep -db pep -num 6 -max 1 -o 6 > specie.p.outfmt6
blastx -q specie.fa -db pep -num 6 -max 1 -o 6 > specie.x.outfmt6
blastp -q specie.pep -db pep -num 6 -max 1 -o 6 > specie.p.outfmt6
```

Desired output

```
blastx -q dog.fa -db pep -num 6 -max 1 -o 6 > dog.x.outfmt6
blastp -q dog.pep -db pep -num 6 -max 1 -o 6 > dog.p.outfmt6
blastx -q worm.fa -db pep -num 6 -max 1 -o 6 > worm.x.outfmt6
blastp -q worm.pep -db pep -num 6 -max 1 -o 6 > worm.p.outfmt6
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying. First you say you want to replace the first two matches, then you say you want to skip the first two matches. Which is it? Maybe show sample input and the desired output.

Comment: can you provide a sample input / output .

Comment: I provided an example above.

Comment: I don't know what that example is supposed to be showing us. You've replaced the word specie with the names of some animals and you say that's `after some rounds of code skipping the first 2, the first 4, etc.`. Huh? Do you by any chance have a list of animal names and you want to replace the word "specie" with each of those names going 2 lines at a time?

Comment: I answered below, you are right I just could pass a list, I didn't know the way to handle that.

Comment: Are the lines really equal? Can you use `for animal in dog worm horse; do blastx -q ${animal}.fa -db pep -num 6 -max 1 -o 6 > ${animal}.x.outfmt6;blastp -q ${animal}.pep -db pep -num 6 -max 1 -o 6 > ${animal}.p.outfmt6; done`

Comment: you can use [address ranges](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/3120/address-and-address-range#t=201609230628274490599) to substitute on specific lines.. for ex:  `sed '1,2 s/specie/dog/g ; 3,4 s/specie/worm/g' ip.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ awk -v animals='monkey worm dog' 'BEGIN{split(animals,a)} NR%2{c++} {$NF=a[c]} 1' file
here some text -t monkey
and then do something -t monkey
here some text -t worm
and then do something -t worm
here some text -t dog
and then do something -t dog
```

Given your new sample input/output maybe this is what you want:

```
$ awk -v animals='dog worm' 'BEGIN{split(animals,a)} NR%2{c++} {gsub(/specie/,a[c])} 1' file
blastx -q dog.fa -db pep -num 6 -max 1 -o 6 > dog.x.outfmt6
blastp -q dog.pep -db pep -num 6 -max 1 -o 6 > dog.p.outfmt6
blastx -q worm.fa -db pep -num 6 -max 1 -o 6 > worm.x.outfmt6
blastp -q worm.pep -db pep -num 6 -max 1 -o 6 > worm.p.outfmt6
```

Since you didn't include any regexp characters or backreference characters or partial match cases in your sample input/output (e.g. if the word `species` appeared somewhere and should NOT be changed) I assume they can't happen and so we don't need the script to guard against them.